# how does o_sync trigger pdflush?

Tags: linux, filesystems, io, cache

When I write using `o_sync`, the write call returns once the data has been written to the disk. But how does `o_sync` force Linux to write the data to disk?

Normally you would have to wait a maximum of `dirty_expire_centisecs +dirty_writeback_centisecs` (30seconds + 5seconds) at worst for `pdflush` to write the data to disk.

Does `o_sync` set the `dirty_expire_centisecs` for the data lower or does something other happen (manually calls flush)?

Please provide sources for your answer. I couldn't find anything on this topic.

Comment: I doubt it would change a system-wide tunable just because you opened a file `O_SYNC`. I'm not an expert on the I/O subsystem but I would imagine it manually wakes/spawns a pdflush thread for each write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sankalp mentioned, pdflush thread is not involved with writes on a file with O_SYNC flag set. It happens in thread context. To get the exact code path taken by kernel you could use ftrace to trace write syscall. I am able to test the same and documented [here](https://vcheru.blogspot.ca/2015/11/file-write-with-osync-enabled.html) on my blog

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary for flushing to happen in the context of pdflush thread. In the case of O_SYNC and the fsync call, the flushing happens in the context of the thread invoking the write/sync system call. The code path in the o_sync case goes roughly as:

__vfs_write -> (f_op->write_iter)/generic_file_write_iter -> generic_write_sync -> (f_op->fsync) -> filemap_write_and_wait_range -> do_writepages -> write_cache_pages -> (f_op->writepage)

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is right but i am going to mark VenkatC's answer as the right one because he provided documentation